# In Bolts, how do you use continueWith() vs continueWithTask()?

Tags: android, bolts-framework

Besides sync vs async, the differences in their documentation is confusing to me. The examples on their [github page](https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-Android#chaining-tasks-together) still look like the continuations are being called synchronously.

`continueWith()
Adds a synchronous continuation to this task, returning a new task that completes after the continuation has finished running.`

`continueWithTask()
Adds an asynchronous continuation to this task, returning a new task that completes after the task returned by the continuation has completed.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you have helper methods that return a `Task` object, you cannot use `continueWith()` or `onSuccess()` because the Bolts code won't treat it as a `Task` and wait for its execution. It would treat the `Task` as a simple data result.

Basically, this won't work, because the resulting task of this chain is a `Task<Task<Void>>`:

```
update().onSuccess(new Continuation<ParseObject, Task<Void>>()
{
  public Task<Void> then(Task<ParseObject> task) throws Exception
  {
    return Task.delay(3000);
  }
}) // this end returns a Task<Task<Void>>
```

But this will work and the chain will return a `Task<Void>`:

```
update().onSuccessTask(new Continuation<ParseObject, Task<Void>>()
{
  public Task<Void> then(Task<ParseObject> task) throws Exception
  {
    return Task.delay(3000);
  }
}) // this end returns a Task<Void>
```